# ormlite dao delete function not taking parameters

Tags: android, ormlite

Trying to delete all records from table on a already built app. I has ormlite dao and the function seems very simple

`allUsers` have a collection of objects to be deleted but i get an Exception :-

> SQLException 
>   "java.sql.SQLException: Unable to run delete collection stmt: DELETE FROM `user` WHERE `PIN` IN  ?,?,?,?,?,)

I tried creating a list of ids and using another option "deleteById" same error

`Collection<UserModel> allUsers = helper.getUserDao().queryForAll();
helper.getUserDao().delete(allUsers);`

I just need the table to be wiped out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it

```
helper.getUserDao().deleteBuilder().where().eq($yourKey, $yourValue).delete()
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain why this code helps and what it does.

Comment: This worked for me! thanks. Any Idea why the other code don't work?

Answer (score 0):

> I tried creating a list of ids and using another option "deleteById" same error
>
> ```
> Collection<UserModel> allUsers = helper.getUserDao().queryForAll();
> helper.getUserDao().delete(allUsers);
> ```

I'm not sure why this didn't work.  If you show more of the exception there may be `Caused by` sections of the exception that provided more details.  It could be that the `UserModel` doesn't have an ID field?

> I just need the table to be wiped out.

There are a couple of ways to do this.  The most efficient is use [`TableUtils.clearTable(...)`](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/table/TableUtils.html#clearTable-com.j256.ormlite.support.ConnectionSource-java.lang.Class-):

```
TableUtils.clearTable(header.getUserDao().getConnectionSource(), UserModel.class);
```

Deleting all of the elements can also be done with the [`DeleteBuilder`](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/stmt/DeleteBuilder.html):

```
helper.getUserDao().deleteBuilder().delete();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Gray. The `UserModel` has an id field, it is a string tough. I try creating a new id field integer auto generated but was getting the exact same error. I'll keep in mind your other recommendations for truncating tables. Regards!